# How to get the `keywords` from html use `portia`

Tags: scrapy, portia

Now I want to scrapy the `keywords` meta and `description` from a web page,like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="A,B,C">
<meta name="description" content="the description a page">
....
```

I google yestoday, but have not idea, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need scrapy to do this. You can just do it with the standard library class `HTMLParser`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
try: 
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
except ImportError:
    import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParse(HTMLParser):
    TAG = "meta"
    NAMES = ['keywords', 'description']
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.contents = {}
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == MyHTMLParse.TAG:
            attributes = {i[0] : i[1] for i in attrs}
            if attributes.get("name", None) in MyHTMLParse.NAMES:
                self.contents[attributes["name"]] = attributes["content"]


parser = MyHTMLParse()

# Feed parser the website with parser.feed(), then access the information with
# parser.contents as a dictionary with keys "keywords" and "description"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a portia project, and want to scrapy the `keywords` and `description` in the spider.